# Как запустить несколько Docker containers?

Tags: node.js, сервер, docker

Есть многоядерный сервер, нужно использовать все его ядра, приложение работает как Docker container, деплоится через `wercker`. Использовать node.js `cluster` module не имеет смысла, потому что контейнер использует 1 ядро (**верно ли это?**). Не использую `docker-compose`. Думал о:

1. Всё же использовать [node cluster](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/cluster.html) для создания нескольких инстансов приложения, а при запуске контейнера указать опцию `cpus=CORES_QUANTITY`. Т.е.: если создам 10 инстансов в контейнере и укажу `cpus=10`, то должен запуститься один контейнер с 10 воркерами, который будет использовать 10 ядер. **Но так ли это?**
2. Запустить это как Docker Swarm на единственном сервере. Тогда надо создавать сервис, а линковать, как при создании контейнера, сервис нельзя. А нужно привязать еще некоторые сервисы (БД, к примеру). **Если я создам для них одну `network`, то контейнеры не нужно будет линковать ?** Таким способом:

`docker service create --network primary --replicas 10 MyApp`

`docker service create --network primary --replicas 2 MyDB`

Возможно ли так? И как они будут между собой балансировать, коммуницировать?

Или может есть еще варианты?

Comment: *потому что контейнер использует 1 ядро (верно ли это?)* - конечно нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Не использую docker-compose

Зря. Можно описать сети и просто [деплоить](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stack_deploy/).

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml stack_name
```

Подробнее о [директивах](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/).